# How do i access specific indexes within an array using pointers in C+?

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, indexing

I have a program I am writing that prints out a Fibonacci Sequence up to 30 numbers. I must do this by traversing the array using pointers, but I don't know how to.

There is not a lot of easy to follow information that I can understand.

When I see the code for c++ answers to this, all I see is this...

I'm a noob and I am having a hard time looking at all of the 'std::' conventions when I have to look at code. I know it's probably good convention, but I am not good with it yet. So I would like a straightforward example, assuming I am using the `using namespace std;` line of code within my project.

I have tried setting the for..loop up with the pointer variable but I am not sure how to do this.

```
void fibonacciSequence(){

    //initialize the array and users input
    const int ARRAY_SIZE = 30;
    int numbers[ARRAY_SIZE];
    int *pointer;

    pointer = numbers;


    //Traverse the array and generate the Fibonacci Sequence
    for(int i = 0; i < ARRAY_SIZE; i++){

        //Set first element to 0
        if(i == 0){
            numbers[i] = 0;
        }
        //Set second element to 1
        else if (i == 1){
            numbers[i] = 1;
        }
        //Start calculating the sequence after the first 2 elements
        //have been established.
        else{
            numbers[i] = numbers[(i - 1)] + numbers[(i - 2)];
        }
    }

    // Output the Fibonacci Sequence after calculations.
    for(int i = 0; i < ARRAY_SIZE; i++){
        cout << numbers[i] << endl;
    }

}
```

This code I have works perfectly. But instead of traversing the array using 'i' in the for...loop, i need to use 'pointer.'

Comment: I don't see what the `std` rant adds to your question, but it's always `std::[thing in the standard library]` like `std::cout` or `std::vector`.

Comment: Is this a school assignment?  If so you should have a section on pointer arithmetic in your book that explains this.  If not, why do you have such a requirement?

Comment: I am teaching myself how to use pointers and someone told me to learn how to use them in loops. that is why I am trying to find out how to do so. So I created this Fibonacci application to try and practice with it, but I do not know how to use pointers IN the loop to do what the code is currently doing.

Comment: If you want to learn C++, I suggest using a [good C++ book](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list).  They will cover this in the book, plus a whole lot more.  C++ is a very complicated language and really requires a strong foundation to use correctly.

Comment: I would like to note that I have been told by various people that using pointers in loops with arrays is a common practice and is commonly used in the workplace. Please correct me if I am wrong because I AM learning and ANY constructive criticism is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's actually very simple change this

```
for(int i = 0; i < ARRAY_SIZE; i++){
    cout << numbers[i] << endl;
}
```

to this

```
for(int* p = numbers; p < numbers + ARRAY_SIZE; p++){
    cout << *p << endl;
}
```

Explanation

`int* p = numbers` - set p to point to the beginning of the array

`p < numbers + ARRAY_SIZE` - check p hasn't reached the end of the array

`p++` - move p on to the next element of the array

`*p` - access the element that p is pointing to

Similar changes to your first loop.

This whole topic is *pointer arithmetic*, maybe you could do some research.

Answer (score 1):

This probably isn't a good project for learning pointers, since indexing is the most natural way of computing a fibanocci sequence. But here goes. Replace that generator loop with this:

```
int *current = numbers;
*current++ = 0;
*current++ = 1;
while (current != numbers + ARRAY_SIZE) {
    *current = *(current - 1) + *(current - 2);
    ++current;
}
```

And then for the output:

```
for (current = numbers; current != numbers + ARRAY_SIZE; ++current)
    std::cout << *current << '\n';
```